# PHP / phpMyAdmin error on exporting feature with zip or gzip

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, zip, gzip

I have the same xampp 5.6.8 configuration on 3 different machines using windows.
Only in one machine, when I export a database with phpMyAdmin (that has 2mb of plain text sql) if I use zip or gzip as output, the generated file is a mix between plain text at the beginning and binary after a few page down on the editor. It's really weird.

Any hint?
Does anyone had this problem before?

Comment: I have actually experienced similar issues with compression too. I exported without compression and that's it. bzip2 or xz offer better compression anyway, so just compress the downloaded file :-) Maybe an issue in the phpmyadmin implementation? Who knows? Probably the implementation contains an endless handler switch to try different compression utilities that might or might not be available on a system. Such thing never is fun to debug. But give it a try (since this is a place to ask _programming related questions_)...

Comment: I've been developing a website and my first thought was to ask here but you are right, this is not the correct place to ask this question.  
Thanks anyway!! What you told me it's helpful.